# How to aggregate several columns into a JSON file for each group in HIVE

Tags: sql, json, hive

I want to convert the following table into a new table with two rows. In the new table, each `user_id` has one JSON file to summarize all other columns in the first table.

`user_id reservation_id  nights  price 
AAA     10001             1     100
AAA     10002             1     120
BBB     20003             7     350`

to 

`user_id    reservation_details
AAA        {10001:{'nights':1, 'price':100}, 10002:{'nights':1, 'price':120}}
BBB        {20003:{'nights':7, 'price':350}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      user_id
           ,concat("{",concat_ws(',',collect_list(concat(string(reservation_id),":{'nights':",string(nights),",'price':",string(price),"}"))),"}")  as reservation_details

from        mytable

group by    user_id
```

---

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id |                       reservation_details                       |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| AAA     | {10001:{'nights':1,'price':100},10002:{'nights':1,'price':120}} |
| BBB     | {20003:{'nights':7,'price':350}}                                |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! A little twist makes it work it HIVE by replacing `string(varname)` with `cast(varname as string)`

Comment: You're welcome :-) This is a tested code. What Hive version are you using?

Comment: hive-common-0.13.1-cdh5.3.3.jar

Comment: Is there a json_dump function in hive ?

Comment: It's not a good solution because it cannot deal with a column which contains  ```{``` or ```}``` ,etc ......

Comment: It answers the OP request, in the context determined within the question. The result is not even a valid JSON. The keys are integers and not strings and It uses single quotes instead of double quotes. Where exactly would you expect to bump into `{` or `}` in this context?