# How Can I make a kind of column by distribution in a column in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, histogram, hiveql

I want to make a result in hive like this :

```
| COL1 | HISTOGRAM             |
+------+-----------------------+
|  a   | {"A":2, "B":2}        |
|  b   | {"C":2, "A":1, "B":1} |
```

from this table :

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
+------+------+
| a    | A    |
| a    | B    |
| a    | A    |
| a    | B    |
| b    | A    |
| b    | B    |
| b    | C    |
| b    | C    |
```

Presto SQL has like what I want, I think :

```
select COL1, histogram(COL2)
from sample_table 
group by COL1
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44363446/5841306) answer your question ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Oh that is similar with mine, but mine needs an aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate counts group by col1, col2, then aggregate col2:cnt strings using `collect_set` or `collect_list` into array, concatenate array with comma as a delimiter and convert resulting string to map using `str_to_map`.

Demo:

```
select stack (8, --number of tuples
 'a','A'
,'a','B'
,'a','A'
,'a','B'
,'b','A'
,'b','B'
,'b','C'
,'b','C'
) as (COL1,COL2)
)

select col1, str_to_map(concat_ws(',',collect_set(concat(col2,':',cnt)))) histogram
from
(
select col1, col2, count(*) cnt from data_example group by col1, col2
)s
group by col1
;
```

Result:

```
col1    histogram
a   {"A":"2","B":"2"}
b   {"A":"1","B":"1","C":"2"}
```